# Doubt on understanding continuity .

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Just preparing for my multivariable-calculus exam and wanted to clear these things:

I've come across many questions of sort below ,*especially 2-dimensional regions*, and wanted to understand the Idea behind them....
Prove the continuity of $f(x,y)$ on $\mathbb R^2$where,

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \text{some fn./value is given} & \text{, if x,y in region1 } \\ \text{some other fn./value is given} & \text{, if x,y in region2} \end{cases}$$

Here ,region $1$ and region $2$ consist of all those points $(x,y)$ satisfying respective inequalities in $x$ and $y$...

> to clearly understand my above statements consider example:  $$f(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}  e^{-\text(\frac{1}{|x-y|})} & \text{if $x\neq y$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x=y$} \end{cases} $$

Now if I've to prove continuity on $\mathbb R^2$ :

**STEP 1**: I should pick up any $(x_0,y_0)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ where continuity can be proved,

**STEP 2**: Now what I've to show that limit of $f(x,y)$ where $(x,y)$ are in region $1$ must be equal to limit of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$.
similarly ,show the above for region $2$.

Am I correct with this procedure.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: prove that the function is continuous whenever at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ whenever $x_0\ne y_0$. Should be evident since the function is a composition of continuous functions.

Step 2: prove that the function is also continuous at the points $(x_0,x_0)$ for arbitrary $x_0$. Should be also doable. Hint: $$|f(x,y)-f(x_0,x_0)| =|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y)+f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,x_0)|. $$

Comment: thanks for answer..but can you please help me on this doubt:  where in step-2 did you take care that $f(x,y)$ should be what i.e. what did you consider $(x,y)$ to belonging to ...region-1 or region-2....Please help .I'm confused...

Comment: Your function is defined on two sets: $\{x\ne y\}$ and on $\{x=y\}$ (only the first one is region, by the way). The first one is an open set. Therefore, I take any point $(x_0,y_0)$ in that set, and consider the value $\lim|f(x,y)- f(x_0,y_0)|$ as $(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)$. By some argument we prove that the limit is zero. Thus, the function is continuous on the set $\{x\ne y\}$. Then I want to prove that my function is also continuous on the second set. So I take a point $(x_0,x_0)$ and prove that $\lim|f(x,y)- f(x_0,x_0)|=0$ as $(x,y)\to(x_0,x_0)$. Therefore, the function is continuous everywhere.